# matplotlib tight layout with plots and Slider object

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, slider

I am trying to code a data analysis tool consisting of one matplotlib window drawing two graph one above each other and one Sliding bar to interact with one of the plots.

In the current state, it looks like that:

[image]

My problem is that I want to use as much space as available in the window and for so I am making a call to `tight_layout()` before drawing but the slider object is not moved below the graphs, it stays at the position I draw it first using:

```
axamp  = plt.axes([0.1, 0, 0.8, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)
samp = Slider(axamp, 'Amp', 0.1, 10.0, valinit=a0)
```

Is there a way to have it moved below the graph still using `tight_layout()` and not having to give canvas positions manually to all objects in the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not figure it out with `tight_layout()`, but you can play around with [`subplots_adjust()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html). It will get you there after a bit of manual tweaking. 
The point is to set the `bottom` parameter high enough, so all of your sliders fit bellow the subplots. With `left`, `right`, `top` you can set the margins so your subplot fills as much space as you wish. By utilizing the `wspace` and `hspace`, you can set how much of the space is used in between the individual subplots.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 4, figsize=(9,10))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, bottom=0.15, right=0.95, top=0.98, wspace=0.05, hspace=0.05)
```

If your subplots contain `imshow`, then also `figsize` comes into play, because the default for `aspect` parameter is `None`, which ensures the pixels are squares. So either play with the `figsize` or set `aspect='auto'` if you do not mind stretched images.